How to install LOIC on Parrot OS VM
I've been trying install LOIC on my Parrot OS VM which running using UTM on my M3 Mac. When I try to install it I get the following:

What's going wrong?

debian is not parrot, and the debian tag explicitly asks users to not use it for derivative distros, so I removed that tag :) Welcome here! It would seem you're tring to install 32 bit wine on a security-research specific distro. Is that really the platform you want to do that on, or would you rather use a general-purpose distro (like the actual debian) that supports a wider range of use cases?

That is the platform I want to work with, because ParrotSec is a distro designed for pen-testing, and it has a lot of other tools I use. The tool I need to use in conjunction is low orbit ion cannon (LOIC). LOIC however is a windows tool, so I want to run it using wine32.

Try on this way: https://medium.com/@whcyberus/installing-low-orbit-ion-cannon-loic-in-kali-linux-debian-3132b0cd698a

What @RomeoNinov suggested worked for my secondary goal. But I still wonder how I get WINE to work on my ParrotSec machine.


Clean your apt package cache
sudo sh -c "apt-get update;apt-get dist-upgrade;apt-get autoremove;apt-get autoclean" 


Enable i386 architecture
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update


Reinstall backports with the command:
sudo apt install wine32 -t lory-backports


Validate by running
wine —-version && wine




Explanation
Your (or more accurately, ParrotOS') apt policies are causing the problem.
For example, wine32 is requesting (transitively) libdw1:i386 @ >=0.126 but your apt policies for that package explicitly forbid you from installing that installation target.
To view current apt policies which apply to a particular package (with architecture either amd64 or i386):
apt policy PACKAGE:{amd64,i386}

e.g.
apt policy libdw1:{amd64,i386}

This will likely reveal that either libdw1, or one of its dependencies, has already been installed from parrot-backports, so you need to install wine32 from parrot-backports too (see below).
What you should (probably) do
Clean up your apt package installations:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

Ensure i386 architecture is enabled:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

Fix-broken install (for good measure):
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install

Install wine from parrot-backports:
sudo apt-get install -t parrot-backports wine32

Sources

Reddit post
stack exchange question

